# Would you violate the idempotency principle of REST for the sake of performance?

Tags: performance, rest, http, architecture, restful-architecture

I'm working on a low latency app for telecommunications industry where the main workflow triggered a computation as follows:

1. Call a REST API (POST /workflow +payload)
2. REST web app will perform highly parallelized processing in an fast access cache store
3. the rest call will return a response (maybe a JSON object of 4 or 5 fields)

Now, my initial idea adhering to REST design principles, is to do 2 REST API calls, one that POSTS to trigger the processing, then returns a 201 with the location of the processing result in the header (because my understanding is REST calls can either change or return a resource, but not both), then automatically redirects to the GET call.

Now remember I'm trying to reduce latency as much as possible, and HTTP redirects obviously increase that. Is it OK if I make my POST return the payload instead of redirecting to a GET? What are the implications?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a POST is not an idempotent method to begin with, so it not really possible for a POST not to "violate idempotency."

Second, there is no reason a POST may not return a representation of the newly created resource. In fact, according to RFC7231 (one of the new replacements for RFC2616) it may even be cached for subsequent GETS. See section 4.3.3:

> For cases where an origin server wishes the client to be able to cache
>   the the result of a POST in a way that can be used by a later GET, the
>   origin server MAY send a 200 (OK) response containing the result and a
>   Content-Location header field...